# Need last 3 dates average of data available

Tags: sql

i have taken data from 3 different tables as given below. here i am getting data but only minimum data after comparing with `where Convert(Varchar(10),DWA.Date,111)<convert(Varchar(10),DFD.Date_of_Filling,111)`.

I need complete data available in table MD but not getting due to where condition. kindly help.

Not only that i need last 3 dates available average for `AVG(cast(DWA.Airtel as int)) as Avg_DG_Run`.

Kindly help

```
SELECT md.IndusID, 
       md.Site_Name, 
       md.ANCHOR_OPCO, 
       md.DISTRICT, 
       md.TECH_NAME, 
       md.TECH_No, 
       md.OME_Technical_Manager_Name, 
       md.DIESEL_FILLER, 
       md.DIESEL_FILLER_MOB, 
       md.EB_DG, 
       md.Min_Stock_Req, 
       md.Actual_CPH, 
       Sum(Cast(dfd.Qty_Filled AS INT))                    AS This_Month_Filling 
       , 
       Max(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DFD.Date_of_Filling, 111)) AS 
       Last_Filling_Date, 
       Avg(Cast(DWA.Airtel AS INT))                        AS Avg_DG_Run, 
       Sum(Cast(DWA.DG_RUN AS INT))                        AS DGRun 
FROM   MasterData MD 
       LEFT JOIN DieselFillingData DFD 
              ON md.IndusID = dfd.Site_ID 
       LEFT JOIN DayWiseAlarm DWA 
              ON md.IndusID = dwa.Indus_ID 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DWA.Date, 111) < 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DFD.Date_of_Filling, 111) 
GROUP  BY md.IndusID, md.Site_Name, md.ANCHOR_OPCO, md.DISTRICT, md.TECH_NAME, 
          md.TECH_No, md.OME_Technical_Manager_Name, md.DIESEL_FILLER, 
          md.DIESEL_FILLER_MOB, md.EB_DG, md.Min_Stock_Req, md.Actual_CPH 
ORDER  BY md.OME_Technical_Manager_Name, 
          md.TECH_NAME
```

Comment: Remove the `where` condition if it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Sir But i need where condition too for completing my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I see.  The `where` condition it turning the outer joins into inner joins.  Move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
FROM MasterData MD LEFT JOIN
     DieselFillingData DFD 
     ON md.IndusID = dfd.Site_ID LEFT JOIN
     DayWiseAlarm DWA 
     ON md.IndusID = dwa.Indus_ID AND
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DWA.Date, 111) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DFD.Date_of_Filling, 111)
```

Converting dates to strings for comparison seems like a bad idea.  This should do what you want:

```
FROM MasterData MD LEFT JOIN
     DieselFillingData DFD 
     ON md.IndusID = dfd.Site_ID LEFT JOIN
     DayWiseAlarm DWA 
     ON md.IndusID = dwa.Indus_ID AND
        DWA.Date < DFD.Date_of_Filling
```